# Mapsto vs. rightarrow

Tags: math-mode, symbols

This is perhaps half a math question and half a typesetting one. In what circumstances do I use `\mapsto` and when `\rightarrow`? I feel like the standard seems to be: when you're specifying the operator you use `\rightarrow`, but if you're just saying that one domain maps to another you use `\mapsto`. Is that correct?

e.g. I would say `Q\times\Gamma\mapsto Q` but `\delta:Q\times\Gamma\rightarrow Q`.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651205/regarding-the-notation-f-a-mapsto-b

Comment: [Use of ↦ and →](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/936558/874001)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You use `\mapsto` to denote the actual function mapping. For example, consider the function `$f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$` given by `$f(n)=5n$`. You could write that second part as `$n\mapsto5n$`.

Comment: See also the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29#Notation).

Comment: The `\mapsto` notation is useful for talking about a function without inventing a name for it, e.g. "the map `$\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$` given by `$x\mapsto x^2$` is not injective". Note that `\to` is a nice shorthand for `\rightarrow`, which at the same time is more semantic.

Comment: I'd prefer using `\colon` instead of `:`; in fact I'd even more prefer `$f\from\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$`, with `\newcommand*\from{\colon}`.

Comment: @Hendrik: I like the idea of using `\from`. I think I've seen equal numbers of `:` and `\colon` in books (or the equivalent spacing) so I think it's just up to personal preference (or editor preference, really). I have no strong feelings on that one.

Comment: @TH., Is the difference only semantic, or is the visual display of the arrows actually different?

Comment: @Pacerier: There is a visible difference in the colon spacings between `:` and `\colon`. The former has equal spacing on each side (it's a `\mathrel`, I think), while the latter has greater spacing on the right. That is, `f : A \to B` renders as "*f* : *A* → *B*," while `f \colon A \to B` renders as "*f*: *A* → *B*."

Comment: It's an old question that Pacerier asks, but about arrows not colons; for any future reader, yes, there is a visual difference - a `\mapsto` arrow has the 'bar' on the non-pointy end. ([See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29#Notation).)

Comment: @OJFord I think he meant the difference between `\rightarrow` and `\to`. The answer is no.